# Remove appendices page keep individual appendices

Tags: appendices

I am using the report class and want to eliminate the Appendices page without eliminating the actual individual appendices.  I have the capitalization of the appendices as I want (all caps).  I am trying to:

1. Remove the Appendices page (page 5)
2. Remove Appendices page from the Bookmarks and un-nest the individual Appendices from the previous `part`
3. Remove Appendices page from TOC

So currently the setup at the bottom looks like this:

**Bookmarks**
[image]

**TOC**
[image]

**Pages**
[image]

I'd like it to look like (I cut and pasted the images to make them look this way; i.e., I don't have code that made the desired output pics)...

**Bookmarks**
[image]

**TOC**
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage[title,titletoc,toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue,
}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} 

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\newpage
\pdfbookmark[section]{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents 

\part{Top Level}
\chapter{First Chapter}
Foo
\chapter{Last Chapter}
Bar

%% Appendices
\begin{appendices}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{APPENDIX}

\chapter{Foo}
some text

\chapter{Bar}
some more text
\end{appendices}

%% References
\newpage
\singlespacing
\bookmarksetup{startatroot}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{REFERENCES}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{REFERENCES}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

Using @barbara beeton's suggestion (and dumping the appendix package):

```
\appendix
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{APPENDIX}

\chapter{Foo}
some text

\chapter{Bar}
some more text
```

But this Removes the `APPENDIX` prefix and does not un-nest the individual appendices bookmarks from the last `part` bookmark (They're under `Top Level`) so they look more like `REFERENCES`

[image]

Comment: the `report` class has a command `\appendix` which merely changes the numbering system for `\chapter` to use letters, and changes "Chapter" to "Appendix".  i don't know the `appendix` package, but am pretty sure that it's the `appendix` environment from that package that is adding the extra page.  try omitting that and just using the simple `\appendix`.  enclose it in a group if the running heads in the bibliography are affected adversely.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you for your suggestion.  That's where I started from but there were no `APPENDIX` prefix and the appendices bookmarks were still nested under the last `part`.  I show this in the edit above.

Comment: i think i've found an easy fix; i can't promise it doesn't have other side effects, but it looks reasonable.  restore the `appendix` package, and in your preamble, add the line `\renewcommand{\addappheadtotoc}{}`.

Comment: Via section 2 of the [appendix documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/appendix/appendix.pdf), it appears that the `page` option in your `\usepackage` line is what causes the extra separator page. You may only want to use the `title` and `titletoc` options instead.

Comment: @MikeRenfro this is the best option I think to get rid of the Appendices page.  Thank you.  Any thought on how to un-nest the Appendix A and Appendix B from under Part 1?

Comment: Ahh then Add `\bookmarksetup{startatroot}` forore each of the appendices.  @MikeRenfro & @barbarabeeton both of you were very helpful.  Mike if you don't want to put your comment in as an answer I will for future searchers.

Comment: Go ahead and post an answer. Mine wasn't complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @MikeRenfro's comment:

> Via section 2 of the appendix documentation, it appears that the page option in your `\usepackage` line is what causes the extra separator page. You may only want to use the `title` and `titletoc` options instead.

I also added `\bookmarksetup{startatroot}` for each of the appendices to un-nest them from `part 1`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}
\renewcommand{\addappheadtotoc}{}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue,
}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\usepackage{tocloft}
%\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} 
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} 

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\newpage
\pdfbookmark[section]{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents 

\part{Top Level}
\chapter{First Chapter}
Foo
\chapter{Last Chapter}
Bar

%% Appendices
\begin{appendices}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{APPENDIX}
\bookmarksetup{startatroot}
\chapter{Foo}
some text

\bookmarksetup{startatroot}
\chapter{Bar}
some more text
\end{appendices}

%% References
\newpage
\singlespacing
\bookmarksetup{startatroot}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{REFERENCES}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{REFERENCES}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```